# When is a Future task finished

Tags: java, concurrency, future

Is a Future task considered finished, `isDone()==true` when it hits the return statement? 
For example:

```
ExecutorService executor = newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<> result = executor.submit(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                   return;
                }
            }
```

Is result considered done when it hits the `return` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completion of `Future.get` is considered to pin point a `Future`'s completion.

To quote from [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

*A Future represents the result of an asynchronous computation. Methods are provided to check if the computation is complete, to wait for its completion, and to retrieve the result of the computation. **The result can only be retrieved using method get when the computation has completed, blocking if necessary until it is ready.** Cancellation is performed by the cancel method. Additional methods are provided to determine if the task...*

In other words till the time `Future` doesn't complete the call to `Future.get` will be blocked and hence completion of `Future.get` should be considered as completion of `Future` (*normal or exceptional*)

**P.S.:** `Future.isDone` should only be used to check the status and no way an indication as when the `Future` was completed.

Answer (score 3):

More or less.  The javadoc is ambiguous for what it exactly means but generally, when the callable returns, very shortly after `isDone()` will be true (or if an exception occurs the same is true).